# Max value from several row

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, rdd

I have such a DF. I am working on tables in the form of rdd

[image]

I would like to get a table with the maximum order value for a given country and the customer number for this customer.

I have no idea how to construct the map function. Unless there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

With `PySpark`:

```
df.groupBy('customernumber', 'city').max('sum_of_orders')
```

With `Pandas`:

```
df.groupby(['customernumber', 'city'])['sum_of_orders'].max()
```

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Not completey.. :/

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonPartitioner. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonPartitioner([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Long]) does not exist
 [...]
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
 at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I need something like that df.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x: (some function))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716047/pyspark-grouby-and-then-get-max-value-of-each-group may solve your problem.

Comment: at first glance, I think so :D thanks a lot

Comment: I closed your question. If this does not solve your problem, contact me here.